# Background and text colors interaction

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to set background color in my application and print some text over it. It turns out that the default text color and the background color overlap each other if I am not setting the text color explicitly (see the picture below). Why is this happening? Is there any way to get rid of background transparency without setting the text color explicitly?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:background="#ff00ff00"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="120sp"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"
                    android:text="text" />

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/name"
                    android:textSize="120sp"
                    android:text="text" />

        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually the default color of texts is grey(*not black), so its the basic functionality of android system. If you want your text as Black color your have to mention it explicitly.

Else you can make a new style TextView(*Renderer) with default text color as black and use it everywhere.